# Как будет выглядеть регулярное выражение для номера телефона?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как будет выглядеть регурное выражение для номера телефона только такого вида например +7(345) 555-55-55

нашла вариант для проверки номера теелфона такого вида +7345555555

```
        /^\+7[345689]{1}\d{9}$/
```

как его модифицировать под мой вариант? +7(345) 555-55-55

```
      /^\+7\([345689]\){1}\d{9}$/
```

Comment: просто добавьте скобки туда, где они нужны. Круглые скобки надо экранировать, так что записывайте их в виде `\(`

Comment: вот так? что-то не выходит
(вставил в сообщение код)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужен трехзначный код `345`

```
/^\+7\(345\) \d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/
```

[Тест](https://regex101.com/r/Plsasz/1)

Если нужен любой трехзначный код

```
/^\+7\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/
```

[Тест](https://regex101.com/r/klROVj/1)